# Adicionando arquivos no pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Quando eu uso a opção `--onefile`, meu programa não consegue encontrar os arquivos adicionados ao `.exe`.  Eu não sei qual caminho especificar para o meu programa encontrar os arquivos.

Meu código está assim:

```
import  winsound 

winsound.PlaySound ('a.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Answer (score -1):

pyinstaller --hidden-import= winsound --onefile nome_do_seu_arquivo.py
lembrando que voce pode utilizar -F no lugar de --onefile